# How do I change the :-moz-placeholder color with jQuery once it's set?

Tags: jquery, css, html, placeholder

I am running into a problem where if a input field's background color is changed, the placeholder color will blend in too much.

I have already solved the readable text color problem so it's returning the proper light or dark color correctly.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set the CSS property to the calculated color for the specific input box. Please give some guidence?

```
input:-moz-placeholder
{
    color: #BBBBBB;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: #BBBBBB;
}
```

The returned color is `#222222` but the `$('#input').css()` call does not work since it targets the elements CSS directly and not the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this solution, I first dynamically append a style block to the <head> on page load:

```
// add style block to the <head> with default placeholder css on page load
var defaultColor = 'BBBBBB';
var styleContent = 'input:-moz-placeholder {color: #' + defaultColor + ';} input::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #' + defaultColor + ';}';
var styleBlock = '<style id="placeholder-style">' + styleContent + '</style>';
$('head').append(styleBlock);
```

Then, to change the placeholder text color I just update the content of the style block:

```
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
styleContent = 'input:-moz-placeholder {color: #' + randomColor + ';} input::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #' + randomColor + ';}'
$('#placeholder-style').text(styleContent);
```

Check out the jsFiddle:

[Change placeholder text color with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/uEB2u/)

Comment: I thank you kindly for this great solution. It worked like a charm :D