# Change input's placeholder's style-attributes for iOS through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

For other browsers, simply setting `#input-element { color: red; }` is sufficient to also color an input's placeholder text (`<input type="text" placeholder="foo" />`).

However, **this is not the case on iOS**; which requires the following instead (perhaps more appropriate, but still):

```
#input-element::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
```

Fine, that's no problem. However, I'm trying to do this with jQuery, without much success. I've tried the following:

```
$("#input-element::-webkit-input-placeholder").css('color', 'red');
$("#input-element").css('::-webkit-input-placeholder', 'color: red'); // not according to .css documentation: I'm aware
```

However, none of these did any change. I'm trying to avoid appending (`$(head).append("<style>..");` the style directly to the document.

**How to change an input's placeholder style-attributes trough jQuery – maintaining iOS compatibility?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without appending to the head. This is basically the same as trying to change the `:hover` properties for a style. It's a pseudo class, and isn't directly modifyable by jQuery's `css` or Javascript's DOM API. You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: Check this solution out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394217/how-do-i-change-the-moz-placeholder-color-with-jquery-once-its-set

Comment: @jValdron That's exactly what the OP said they want to **avoid**

Comment: @Ian I know, but it's probably one of the only solution that's out there, like you've pointed out.

Comment: @jValdron True, but I'm guessing that's the question they already found and were referencing when they said they don't want to use. I never would've thought to use that technique unless I saw that question, but I guess that's just me

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. Adding style to the document dynamically is both messy and harder to manage (especially together with JQM).

Comment: What about inserting the style element right after the input? When the parent is removed, so is the style element.

Comment: @pimvdb I'm no expert; but I think that would make my website unable to validate it's source (context: W3C-validator?

Comment: @Zar: Yes, I guess it would. But if it's impossible to achieve it otherwise, I think valid HTML is of less priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just toggle a CSS class?

CSS:

```
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }

.blue-pl::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#input-element').click(function(){$(this).addClass('blue-pl'); });
```

This worked on my iOS 6 iPhone.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vt99N/1/)